# Powershell - How can I copy full error information in a trap

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell's trap feature because I would like to output full error information when there's an error and I have to reply to the error. Without the use of a trap Powershell will not show me the error information until after the error (and whatever Inquire prompt I responded to).

The problem with using the trap feature is that though I can print the full information using `$error[0]` I can't figure out how to copy it to a string and get the full information. Instead I only get the brief information.

For example, this shows the full information:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
trap {$error[0]; Read-Host -Prompt "Trapped. Press Enter to exit"}
Split-Path -BAD
echo "Running script"
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"

Split-Path : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'BAD'.
At line:3 char:12
+ Split-Path -BAD
+            ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Split-Path], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SplitPathCo 
   mmand

Trapped. Press Enter to exit: 

Split-Path : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'BAD'.
At line:3 char:12
+ Split-Path -BAD
+            ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Split-Path], ParentContainsErrorRecordExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SplitPathCo 
   mmand
```

But if I try to use $error[0] from Write-Host it only shows the brief error information:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
trap {Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black "$($error[0])"; Read-Host -Prompt "Trapped. Press Enter to exit"}
Split-Path -BAD
echo "Running script"
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"

A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'BAD'.
Trapped. Press Enter to exit: 

Split-Path : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'BAD'.
At line:3 char:12
+ Split-Path -BAD
+            ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Split-Path], ParentContainsErrorRecordExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SplitPathCo 
   mmand
```

I want to show the full error information from the trap with color which is why I need Write-Host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$Error[0]` inside a string, `ToString()` is implicitly called, returning only the error string. Use `Out-String` to get the full error output:

```
trap {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black "$($Error[0] | Out-String)"
    Read-Host "Press enter"

}
```

or use `Write-Error` instead:

```
trap {
    Write-Error $Error[0]
    Read-Host "Press enter"

}
```

Comment: The first method works well. The `Write-Error` has strange behavior where it appears the text is truncated, even if I add `Out-String` to it. http://pastebin.com/kxvLQw07